# GAE Error code 104 in request breaks all concurrent request

Tags: java, google-app-engine, filter, servlet-filters

we experience the following error pattern:

1. > The API call urlfetch.Fetch() was cancelled because the overall HTTP
   >   request deadline was reached.; nested exception is
   >   java.io.IOException:
   >   com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CancelledException: The API call
   >   urlfetch.Fetch() was cancelled because the overall HTTP request
   >   deadline was reached.

2.apart from

> com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CancelledException: The API call
>   urlfetch.Fetch() was cancelled because the thread was interrupted
>   while waiting for concurrent API calls.; nested exception is
>   java.io.IOException:
>   com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CancelledException: The API call
>   urlfetch.Fetch() was cancelled because the thread was interrupted
>   while waiting for concurrent API calls

3.subsequent requests coming to GAE app within next few milliseconds fail with the same `Error code 104`

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(getClientHttpRequestFactory());

try {           
    URI uri = new URI("https://sample/" + sessionId);           
    sessionInfo = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, SessionResponse.class);        } catch (Exception e) {             
     System.out.println(e.getMessage());        
}
```

I'm setting timeout for restTemplate as 50sec,, this code is inside an intercepter where every request will migrate to this block of code and executes

I'm using `javax.servlet.Filter`  to migrate requests there i'm getting this 2nd exception

Any solutions for this will be appreciated thanks,,

Appengine-web.xml file

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <runtime>java8</runtime>
    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties" />
    </system-properties>
    <url-stream-handler>urlfetch</url-stream-handler>
    <warmup-requests-enabled>false</warmup-requests-enabled>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Comment: Could you please share your app.yaml?

Comment: @AndreiTigau We didn't configured app.yaml instead of that u can check the above appengine-web.xml file,, this issue i found that i given timeout as 50 sec and each conecurent request are exceding more than 80sec so appengine throwing deadline exception

Comment: @AndreiTigau the same issue i removed the timeout in rest template and checked,, can u able to look into this issue which i got in this link--**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59775177/sockettimeout-exception-in-java-whiile-calling-resttemplate-getforobject**

Answer (score 0):

The error code `104` in App Engine usually means that your instance is facing either OOM issues, either Deadline exceeded exception.

As I understand from your comments in your case, the second issue occurs. An option of solving that would be to set your scaling type to [basic-scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#scaling_elements_basic_scaling). In the situation of basic scaling, your app will timeout only if it does not reply with a response withing 24h.

You can read more about this [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-instances-are-managed#timeout).