# SocketTimeOut Exception in java whiile calling RestTemplate GetforObject

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, filter, servlet-filters

we experience the following error pattern:

> I/O error on GET request for "https://samplepath": Timeout while
>   fetching URL: https://samplepath; nested exception is
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Timeout while fetching URL:
>   samplepath

Code:

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    try {
        URI uri = new URI("https://samplepath);
        sessionInfo = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, SessionResponse.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

This code is written inside the javax.servlet.Filter where all the reuests will migrate to this block of code where in this it will internally call another api

Issue is after i deploy in GAE concurrent request get hits and some of the requests will get response and some are failing or throwing socket timeout exception by doing internal one Api call through resttemplate

Any solution to this issue will be appreciated thanks,,

```
@Component
public class FirstFilter implements Filter {
    public static Map<String, SessionResponse> sesssionDataCacheMap = Collections
            .synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, SessionResponse>());

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        System.out.println("init() method has been get invoked");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
        try {
            System.out.println("doFilter() method is invoked");
            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            System.out.println("Context path is  " + httpServletRequest.getContextPath());

            String sidFromHeader = httpServletRequest.getHeader("sid");

            SessionResponse sessionInfo1 = null;
                        try {
                            sessionInfo1 = getSessionDataFromSessionId(sidFromHeader);
                            System.out.println("Session  present in cache");
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                        }
                        chain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
                        System.out.println("doFilter() method is ended");
            }
    }
    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    System.out.println("destroy method is called");
    }

    private SessionResponse getSessionDataFromSessionId(String sessionId)  {

        SessionResponse sessionInfo = null;
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        try {
            URI uri = new URI("https://samplesessionurl" + sessionId);
            sessionInfo = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, SessionResponse.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return sessionInfo;

    }
```

Appegine-web.xml File--

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
        <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
        <runtime>java8</runtime>
        <system-properties>
            <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties" />
        </system-properties>
        <url-stream-handler>urlfetch</url-stream-handler>
        <warmup-requests-enabled>false</warmup-requests-enabled>
        <manual-scaling>
        <instances>1</instances>
      </manual-scaling>
    </appengine-web-app>
```

Comment: If i add request timeout to rest template it will effect the other concurrent request to wait or current thread,,beacuse appengine will allow max 1min to complete the requests or else it will throw deadlineexceeded exception..(Does apppengine supports mult threading)

Comment: This could happen for different reasons. It could be due to app's configuration, structure of the request or quotas. Could you provide us with your configuration files in order to understand the setup of your application? Also could you post the full log entry in case there is a trace that might be helpful? Could you describe your use case in order to understand why this is intermittent?

Comment: @tzovourn I have added the logic of my filter where every request to my api will call first transfer to this block of code doFilter() method and executing logic

Comment: thanks for the code snippet but we will also need to know if you use app engine flexible or standard and the configuration files as well(.xml or .yaml files). the log entry would also be useful in case there is a trace, we may can troubleshoot.

Comment: @tzovourn Thanks for the reply,, Added appengine-web.xml file and cron.yaml file i have just configured for cron jobs shedular that is not related to trhis issue and i didnt configured web.xml..The logs just i'm trying to print message not full stack trace so i didn't get any info..

Comment: According to documentation [urlfetch()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#urlfetch_timeout) has a default deadline for a fetch set to 5 seconds. Could you try increase it and see if this solves your issue?

Comment: @tzovourn By increasing time for request won't solve my problem,, as it will waits till the request timeout specified and some time if wait time is more than 1 min then appengine will throw dead line exceeded exception